# Turn invalid an empty non required input field

Tags: html, css, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I need to know how to make an *empty-non-required* `input` element invalid.

For example:

```
<input pattern="[0-9]+" title="" />
```

This field is *:valid* by default, as is not required. I need to turn it *:invalid* if it is empty.

Thank you all in advance. Cheers.

**EDIT:**

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" name="Country" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" title="" placeholder="Country" />
    <a href="#">Toggle</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input:valid + a
{
    color: blue;
}
```

The `<a>` starts blue since there is no text inside the `<input>` which is not required.

The pseudo-class *:valid* state for an *empty-non-required* `<input>` element is *true*.

I need the `<a>` to remain *uncolored* when the `<input>` field is empty.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your code? Example? etc...

Comment: why do you need to do this, there is probably a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer addresses the clarified/modified question, which seems to be about styling. An `input` element cannot match the selector `:invalid` if its value is empty, since such an element is exempted from constraint validation (as explained in my first answer). There is no selector for checking that the value of an `input` element is empty or non-empty. (The `:empty` pseudo-class tests for the *content* being empty, and an `input` element always has empty content.)

So this cannot be done in CSS (alone). You can use JavaScript e.g. so that any input operation causes the `input` element value to be checked. If the value is nonempty, put the `input` element to a class, say `ok`. Modify the CSS selector accordingly.

```
 <style>
 input:valid + a.ok {
   color: blue;
 }     
 </style>
 <input ... oninput=check(this)>
 ...
<script>
function check(el) {
  el.nextElementSibling.className = el.value ? 'ok' : '';
}
```

This works in sufficiently modern browsers. If wider browser coverage is needed, you may need to add event attributes like `onkeypress` and `onpaste` etc. that are used to run the same check. (And `nextElementSibling` might need to be replaced by some clumsier way of getting at the next element.)

**Update**, as per the comment below, you can simplify the code somewhat by setting the class on the `input` element rather than the `a` element. This means that the CSS selector would be `input:valid.ok + a` and the JavaScript assignment statement would have just `el.className` as the left-hand side. Regarding browser coverage, it’s probably not an issue here as compared with the basic restriction caused by the use of the [`:valid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3avalid?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/%3avalid) pseudo-class, which isn’t supported by IE 9 and earlier.

Comment: Quite a good answer :) Can I add the class _.ok_ to the `input` itself?

Comment: Yes, that would simplify things. Added an update to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the attribute `required`, which has the same (limited, but growing) browser support as the `pattern` attribute. There is no way to make an “empty non-required” element invalid, because the [`required` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-required-attribute) *means* that the value must be non-empty.

The description of the [`pattern` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute) in HTML5 CR says the attribute is used in constraint validation only if the value is not empty. This could also be said so that an empty string is always regarded as matching the pattern (but it really isn’t even checked against it).

Comment: The problem is that when adding the _required_ attribute I cannot submit the `form` if the `input` is empty. Is there a way to add a _non-empty_ clause to the _pattern_ attribute?

Comment: The very point of using attributes like `pattern` and `required` is that they prevent form submission (and signal errors to the user) when the constraints are not satisfied. So what do you want to do? To make a field required and not make it required?

Comment: No, what I want to do is to make a field non required for submission but still with pattern checking if it is not empty.

Comment: That’s not what you wrote in the question: “I need to turn it :invalid if it is empty.” Consider explaining what the real problem is, i.e. what you are really up to. Including sample code in the question, with an explanation, is a good idea.